# Classify input Text using doc2vec and LogisticRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, text-classification, doc2vec

I'm trying to classify user input text in two categories using doc2vec in python. I have the following code to train model and then classify input text. The problem is, i can't able find any method which classify string. 
I'm newbie so please ignore mistakes.

Here are links for class reference

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.predict
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html

```
# gensim modules
from gensim import utils
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec

# random shuffle
from random import shuffle

# numpy
import numpy

# classifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

import logging
import sys

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(ch)

class TaggedLineSentence(object):
    def __init__(self, sources):
        self.sources = sources

        flipped = {}

        # make sure that keys are unique
        for key, value in sources.items():
            if value not in flipped:
                flipped[value] = [key]
            else:
                raise Exception('Non-unique prefix encountered')

    def __iter__(self):
        for source, prefix in self.sources.items():
            with utils.smart_open(source) as fin:
                for item_no, line in enumerate(fin):
                    yield TaggedDocument(utils.to_unicode(line).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % item_no])

    def to_array(self):
        self.sentences = []
        for source, prefix in self.sources.items():
            with utils.smart_open(source) as fin:
                for item_no, line in enumerate(fin):
                    self.sentences.append(TaggedDocument(utils.to_unicode(line).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % item_no]))
        return self.sentences

    def sentences_perm(self):
        shuffle(self.sentences)
        return self.sentences


log.info('source load')
sources = {'test-neg.txt':'TEST_NEG', 'test-pos.txt':'TEST_POS', 'train-neg.txt':'TRAIN_NEG', 'train-pos.txt':'TRAIN_POS', 'train-unsup.txt':'TRAIN_UNS'}

log.info('TaggedDocument')
sentences = TaggedLineSentence(sources)

log.info('D2V')
model = Doc2Vec(min_count=1, window=10, size=100, sample=1e-4, negative=5, workers=7)
model.build_vocab(sentences.to_array())

log.info('Epoch')
for epoch in range(10):
    log.info('EPOCH: {}'.format(epoch))
    model.train(sentences.sentences_perm())

log.info('Model Save')
model.save('./imdb.d2v')
model = Doc2Vec.load('./imdb.d2v')

log.info('Sentiment')
train_arrays = numpy.zeros((25000, 100))
train_labels = numpy.zeros(25000)

for i in range(12500):
    prefix_train_pos = 'TRAIN_POS_' + str(i)
    prefix_train_neg = 'TRAIN_NEG_' + str(i)
    train_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_train_pos]
    train_arrays[12500 + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_train_neg]
    train_labels[i] = 1
    train_labels[12500 + i] = 0


test_arrays = numpy.zeros((25000, 100))
test_labels = numpy.zeros(25000)

for i in range(12500):
    prefix_test_pos = 'TEST_POS_' + str(i)
    prefix_test_neg = 'TEST_NEG_' + str(i)
    test_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_pos]
    test_arrays[12500 + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_neg]
    test_labels[i] = 1
    test_labels[12500 + i] = 0

log.info('Fitting') 
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(train_arrays, train_labels)

LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001)

print(classifier.score(test_arrays, test_labels))
# classify input text
text = input("Enter Your text:")
print(classifier.predict(text.split()))
```

Answer (score 2):

for your last step, you should use infer() method first, as you need to make a document vector of the text you put in, any new words (for the vocabulary will be ignored). Then pass the resulting document vector to your classifier.

I think there is a difference of using Logistic Regression and the SGD classifier, normally for this size dataset the Logistic Regression should be all you need. Best way is to try with default parameters and then tune once you get it working.

Comment: There is no infer() method in the class. And confused about doc vector. Please can provide any example?

Comment: sorry, infer_vector() good explanation of this part here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/-yyl6VBTM2Q

Comment: this is a decent tutorial, with tweets - https://www.zybuluo.com/HaomingJiang/note/462804 and there is a nice tutorial by M Czerny https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/modern-methods-for-sentiment-analysis which I can recommend, I think he used imdb reviews like you also?